# Resize a bitmap image sized 9000x9000 to 150x150?

Tags: actionscript-3

Is it possible to resize a bitmap image sized 9000x9000 to 150x150? I've heard there are some limits...

Comment: The best way is to try it out yourself.

Comment: Need more details. This is technically possible if you have access to and can pass the ByteArray/file data for that image to an external program (Java, C, PHP, shell script, etc). Flash can't handle BitmapData at that size (see TheDarklnl1978's post), but you might be able to hand it over to another program/script that can.

Answer (score 3):

> BitmapData:  Flash CS5 ActionScript
>   3.0 Language Reference
>
> In AIR 1.5 and Flash Player 10, the
>   maximum size for a BitmapData object
>   is 8,191 pixels in width or height,
>   and the total number of pixels cannot
>   exceed 16,777,215 pixels. (So, if a
>   BitmapData object is 8,191 pixels
>   wide, it can only be 2,048 pixels
>   high.) In Flash Player 9 and earlier
>   and AIR 1.1 and earlier, the
>   limitation is 2,880 pixels in height
>   and 2,880 in width.

Answer (score 0):

PNGEncoder

9000 shouldn't be too high

open the image and then use the PNGEncoder to save the image back out.